# list not updating in class (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, oop

self.cell is not updating..

when ever i enter value  in `cell_in` `update_cell` method does not list cell.
and returns `['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']`

```
class board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cell=['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']

    def display(self):
        x=0
        c= self.cell
        for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                if(j is 0):
                    print(' ',end='')
                print(c[x],end='')
                x+=1
                if(j<2):
                    print(' | ',end='')
            if(i<2):
                print('\n-----------')
        print()



    def update_cell(self,cell_in,player):
        self.cell[(cell_in-1)]= player
def header():
    print("-TicTacToe-")

def ref_scr():
    cls()
    header()
    board().display()
while True:
    ref_scr()
    cell_in = int(input("enter cell between 1 and 9: "))
    player= 'X'
    board().update_cell(cell_in,player)
```

Comment: `board()` creates a new instance of board and `board().update_cell(cell_in,player)` creates a new instance, updates it, and throws it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it should look. This stops the code from initializing a new board object in each loop.

```
def ref_scr(brd):
    cls()  # Not sure what this is. It doesn't appear anywhere else.
    header()
    brd.display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    brd = Board()
    while True:
        ref_scr(brd)
        cell_in = int(input("enter cell between 1 and 9: "))
        player = 'X'
        brd.update_cell(cell_in, player)
```

Edit:
Went ahead and changed the ref_scr func as well. This should now work.

Comment: @SháhrozTanveer "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive.  This is the correct use of a class, however.

Comment: @Myles Hollowed list is still not updating.. when ref_scr() is called the (updated x slot become '-')

Comment: I didn't debug your source. I just showed you the correct way to use the class.

Comment: @SháhrozTanveer You also didn't show what you changed your code to that "still doesn't work".  We told you what was wrong with it, now apply it.

Answer (score 3):

`board()` creates a new board instance each time.  Create one board instance with `brd = board()`, and use it to call `brd.update_cell()` and `brd.display()`.